# How do i test/refactor my tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic

I have a test suit for my app. As the test suit grew organically, the tests have a lot of repeated code which can be refactored.

However I would like to ensure that the test suite doesn't change with the refactor. How can test that my tests are invariant with the refactor.

(I am using Python+UnitTest), but I guess the answer to this can be language agnostic.

Comment: For a quick and dirty solution, you can try checking the coverage before/after the refactor.

Answer (score 5):

The real test for the tests is the production code.

An effective way to check that a test code refactor hasn't broken your tests would be to do [Mutation Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing), in which a copy of the code under test is mutated to introduce errors in order to verify that your tests catch the errors.  This is a tactic used by some test coverage tools.

I haven't used it (and I'm not really a python coder), but this seems to be supported by the [Python Mutant Tester](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymutester), so that might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Coverage.py is your friend.

Move over all the tests you want to refactor into "system tests" (or some such tag). Refactor the tests you want (you would be doing unit tests here right?) and monitor the coverage:

- After running your new unit tests but before running the system tests
- After running both the new unit tests and the system tests.

In an ideal case, the coverage would be same or higher but you can thrash your old system tests.

FWIW, py.test provides mechanism for easily tagging tests and running only the specific tests and is compatible with unittest2 tests.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question - I'm always keen to hear discussions of the type "how do I test the tests?!". And good points from @marksweb above too.

It's always a challenge to check your tests are actually doing what you want them to do and testing what you intend, but good to get this right and do it properly.  I always try to consider the rule-of-thumb that testing should make up *1/3 of development effort* in any project... regardless of project time constraints, pressures and problems that inevitably crop up.

If you intend to continue and grow your project have you considered refactoring like you say, but in a way that creates a proper test framework that allows test driven development (TDD) of any future additions of functionality or general expansion of the project?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could write a test for the test, mocking the actualy object under test.But I guess that is just way to much work and not worth it.

So what you are left with are some strategies, that will help, but not make this fail safe.

1. Work very carefully and slowly. Use the features of you IDEs as much as possible in order to limit the chance of human error.
2. Work in pairs. A partner looking over your shoulder might just spot the glitch that you missed.
3. Copy the test, then refactor it. When done introduce errors in the production code to ensure, both tests find the the problem in the same (or equivalent) ways. Only then remove the original test.
4. The last step can be done by tools, although I don't know the python flavors. The keyword to search for is 'mutation testing'.

Having said all that, I'm personally satisfied with steps 1+2.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have mentioned Python, I would like to comment how refactoring is applied in Smalltalk. Most modern Smalltalk implementations include a "[Refactoring Browser](http://www.refactory.com/tools/refactoring-browser)" integrated in a System Browser to restructure source code. The RB includes a rewrite framework to perform dynamically the transformations you asked about preserving the system behavior and stability. A way to use it is to open a scoped browser, apply refactorings and review/edit changes before commiting through a diff tool. I don't know about maturity of Python refactoring tools, but it took many iteration cycles (years) for the Smalltalk community to have such an amazing piece of software.

Don Roberts and John Brant wrote one of the first refactoring browser tools which now serves as the standard for refactoring tools. There are some [videos](http://vimeo.com/8861620) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jih7QVlbzj8) demonstrating some of these features. For promoting a method into a superclass, in [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org/) you just select the method, refactor and "pull up" menu item. The rule will detect and let you review the proposed duplicated sub-implementors for deletion before its execution. Application of refactorings are regardless of Testing code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an easy way to refactor a test suite, and depending on the extent of your refactor you're obviously going to have to change the test suite. How big is your test suite?

Refactoring properly takes time and attention to detail (and a lot of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>!). Whenever I've refactored my tests I don't try and find any quick ways of doing things, besides find & replace, because there is too much risk involved.

You're best of doing things properly and manually albeit slowly if you want to make keep the quality of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Don't refactor the test suite.

The purpose of refactoring is to make it easier to maintain the code, *not* to satisfy some abstract criterion of "code niceness". Test code doesn't need to be nice, it doesn't need to avoid repetition, but it does need to be thorough. Once you have a test that is valid (i.e. it really does test necessary conditions on the code under test), you should never remove it or change it, so test code doesn't need to be easy to maintain en masse.

If you like, you can rewrite the existing tests to be nice, and run the new tests *in addition to* the old ones. This guarantees that the new combined test suite catches all the errors that the old one did (and maybe some more, as you expand the new code in future).

There are two ways that a test can be deemed invalid -- you realise that it's wrong (i.e. it sometimes fails falsely for correct code under test), or else the interface under test has changed (to remove the API tested, or to permit behaviour that previously was a test failure). In that case you can remove a test from the suite. If you realise that a whole bunch of tests are wrong (because they contain duplicated code that is wrong), *then* you can remove them all and replace them with a refactored and corrected version. You don't remove tests just because you don't like the style of their source.

To answer your specific question: to test that your new test code is equivalent to the old code, you would have to ensure (a) all the new tests pass on your currently-correct-as-far-as-you-known code base, which is easy, but also (b) the new tests detect all the errors that the old tests detect, which is usually not possible because you don't have on hand a suite of faulty implementations of the code under test.

Comment: I fully aggree and might add that when a test case gets outdated it should not be removed, but rather marked with a suitable `@skip...` decorator. This is for documentation and allows you to keep the test case active for the older revision of your code. http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

Comment: I disagree that test code doesn't need to be 'nice'. Once it should serve the purpose of documentation. If you are doing agile TDD it is also a tool for design. If you don't minimize duplication in your tests they are likely to become a pain in the ass if you happen to change the code under test.

Comment: @nansen: that has not been my experience, duplicated tests have never caused me any particular trouble where I have kept them. Further, I would be concerned if anyone was making backward-incompatible changes to the code under test and then assuming that just because they have found and updated one test, that "there's no duplication, so I'm done". And since you mention documentation -- written docs are another thing that I don't compulsively refactor to avoid all repeated text...

Comment: I did not correlate the documenting character of tests with duplication or the reduction thereof. I meant that clean and readable tests are a valuable documentation of the code that's tested. And improved readability is one important goal of refactoring.

Comment: .. but since the argument got started: duplicate documentation is another PITA for exactly the same reasons as duplicated text: Once the documentation has to change (like tomorrow) someone is bound to update only half the places.

Comment: @JensSchauder: so for example in Posix, the phrase "A function that is not required to be reentrant is not required to be thread-safe." is duplicated in many function specs. This is the kind of thing that some eager beaver might want to "refactor" to remove duplication, and they should be restrained by force if necessary ;-) If something ever happens to Posix so disruptive as to change this text, then the editor will just change them all (probably following a judgement, deciding which of the relevant functions now need to be thread-safe and which still don't). There is no problem to solve.

Comment: @SteveJessop a phrase, small and stable as this is probably not a problem at all. But this argument is like saying "since you shouldn't replace every usage of +1 with a method call, the idea of DRY is just wrong." If you look into less carefully managed specifications (i.e. probably most of the specifications in existence) you'll find large pieces of text created by cut and paste (and partial editing of the resulting dubs).

Answer (score 0):

Test code can be the best low level documentation of your API since they do not outdate as long as they pass and are correct. But messy test code doesn't serve that purpose very well. So refactoring is essential.

Also might your tested code change over time. So do the tests. If you want that to be smooth, code duplication must be minimized and readability is a key.

Tests should be easy to read and always test one thing at once and make the follwing explicit:

- what are the preconditions?
- what is being executed?
- what is the expected outcome?

If that is considered, it should be pretty safe to refactor the test code. One step at a time and, as @Don Ruby mentioned, let your production code be the test for the test.

For many refactoring you can often safely rely on advanced IDE tooling – if you beware of side effects in the extracted code.

Although I agree that refactoring without proper test coverage should be avoided, I think writing tests for your tests is almost absurd in usual contexts.